# Cannot access Mysql Docker Container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to access a docker container i have created.
Here are the files.

**DockerFile**

```
FROM mysql:5.7.24

LABEL MAINTAINER Myself <example@example.com>
LABEL description="Immagine DBMS MySql"


ADD dump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

EXPOSE 3390
```

The **dump.sql** creates multiple databases with al the tables for each database.
(Is it possible to do this?)

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.3'

networks: 
  ntalphash:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/24

services:
  mysql:
    build:
      context: .
    image: mysql:5.7.24
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: mysqlsrv
    volumes: 
      - data-volume:/var/lib/mysql
    networks: 
        ntalphash:
          ipv4_address: 172.20.0.2
    ports:
      - target: 3306
        published: 3390
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin

volumes:
  data-volume:
```

Here the commands i'm running on terminal:

Starting the container:

```
PS C:\Sql Server\MySql> docker-compose up                                                                                                                                                     Starting mysqlsrv ... done                                                                                                                                                                    Attaching to mysqlsrv
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.454914Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.455943Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.24) starting as process 1 ...
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.458112Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.458143Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.458148Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.458151Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.458153Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.458155Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.458319Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.458429Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.459511Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.465707Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.467263Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.478653Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.490450Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.490629Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.505991Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.506650Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.506677Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.507334Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.24 started; log sequence number 101589607
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.507516Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.507702Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.509875Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200614 11:07:57
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.511163Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.511449Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.513138Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.513304Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.513313Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.513327Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.515152Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.515869Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.515907Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.515915Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.515920Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'debian-sys-maint@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.515937Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.515939Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.515946Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.516857Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.516888Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.521147Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
mysqlsrv | 2020-06-14T11:07:57.521307Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
mysqlsrv | Version: '5.7.24'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Checking for active containers:

```
C:\Users\Myself>docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                         NAMES
ec9f9070939e        mysql:5.7.24                                        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   27 minutes ago      Up About a minute   3390/tcp, 33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3390->3306/tcp   mysqlsrv
64540c9d4bd1        portainer/portainer                                 "/portainer"             7 days ago          Up 46 minutes       0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp                        portainer
0345722e5fc3        mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest-ubuntu   "/opt/mssql/bin/nonr…"   6 months ago        Up 46 minutes       0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp                        sqlserver
```

Then accessing the container and trying login mysql:

```
C:\Users\Myself>docker exec -ti mysqlsrv bash
root@ec9f9070939e:/# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
root@ec9f9070939e:/#
```

The password i'm typing is 'admin' as this is the password i've specified on the configuration file.
I am a beginner with Docker.
Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: If you've been iterating on this setup, it's possible the `data-volume` contains an older version of the database data with a different root password.  [`docker-compose down -v`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/) will delete that volume; you might try that.

Comment: (You can safely delete all of the `networks:` blocks and `container_name:`; Compose provides reasonable defaults as described in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).  The `image:` line causes Compose to overwrite the base `mysql:5.7.24` image with the one you built, and I would recommend deleting that line and manually `docker pull mysql:5.7.24` to get the standard image back.)

Comment: Deleting the network block i get this error:

ERROR: Service "mysql" uses an undefined network "ntalphash"

Comment: Delete _all_ the `networks:` blocks, including the one inside the service declaration.  Compose will create a network named `default` for you and assign IP addresses on its own.

Comment: Done. Thanks a lot for your help but i'm still facing the same problem...